# Error using DateTimePicker: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object required

Tags: asp.net, html

I'm trying to use DateTimePicker (asp.net 4.0, c#).

When the page is loaded, it's displayed on the screen with the requested date but when I try to change date or do anything else, the "Object Required" exception/error is thrown and I'd like to know how to handle it.

On the top of my page I put

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc1" 
         Namespace="mycompany.WebServerControls.DateTimePicker" 
         Assembly="DateTimePicker" %>
```

The DateTimePicker is declared like this:

```
<cc1:datetimepicker id="dtpStart" runat="server" 
          Width="129px" Height="36px"></cc1:datetimepicker>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: seems like the issue could be with that control, try to create another page having just that control in it and test it, to verify that the control is buggy.

Comment: What control is that ? `mycompany.WebServerControls.DateTimePicker` do you have the website that you get it ?

Comment: Do you see Calendar in drop down mode when you click on it??? check your settings.